# In nowrap mode, is it possible to add a ">" sign to signal there's text rightward that hasn't been displayed?

Tags: wrapping, wrap

So currently I'm disabling wrap in my vim, but I remember in vim when wrap is disabled and the line is too long to display, it would add a ">" at the end of the line so you know the line isn't finished. Yet this doesn't happen when I set nowrap. Is there anyway I could achieve this? Something like following:

```
A very very long and not ending, single line sentence which continu >
```

And when press leftward if would become something like this:

```
< sentence which continues on and on till here, where it fully stops.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `:h 'list'` and `:h 'listchars'`

```
set list listchars=tab:›\ ,extends:→,precedes:←,nbsp:·,trail:·
```

- with `list` you activate `>` and `<`
- with `listchars` you can change `>` and `<` to other symbols if needed, see `extends` and `precedes` parameters.

[image]